# Why was this question reopened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There is a question, [mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli ( it is mysqli though )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108340/mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-it-is-mysqli-though), that genuinely seems to me to be a duplicate of [Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in) in every aspect - the title, the question body, and the answer are almost literally the same.

Yet it has been reopened. Do I fail to see some essential difference or any other reason?

Comment: They certainly look like duplicates to me, with the limited php experience i have.

Comment: I would say that the two questions are duplicates, and the target has a better explanation, good call.

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this question as "Primarily Opinion Based":  Questions asking why a question was reopened are most definitely not off-topic for Meta.

Comment: If anyone is down voting the linked to question/answer please do it for their content and not because of the meta effect.  neither the OP or the answerer should be punished.  They were not involved in any of this.

Comment: My question was answered, I don't see what the fuss is about

Comment: Your Common Sense is rarely nice, but he is often right. The cause of the OP's problem may have been something different than in the linked dupe, but the question in question seems hardly worth reopening - it's a highly localized problem, it's sufficiently answered. Leave it closed.

Comment: But at the same time, this post should not be judged based on the OP's previous actions. This post should be judged based on *its* merits alone. @Jay

Comment: @TinyGiant Context matters though... If the real intent of this post was to generate a meta effect and publicly air an argument, rather than to honestly get feed back on the questions, the context certainly matters.

Comment: If you have a problem with a user's actions that warrants a flag, flag it. Otherwise you can whine about it in chat, but starting an off-topic discussion about a user's past behavior in the comments section of a perfectly on-topic question is not the way to handle the situation.

Comment: You're all so caught up in punishing him for past actions that you don't even both to determine whether or not the action that you are punishing is actually deserving of punishment. If you want to play a game, you have to play by the rules, whether the other party does or not.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with the question being incorrectly reopened. Past actions have nothing to do with this matter, unless the action was taken *because* of past actions, which is of course wrong, and has been corrected.

Comment: The question has just been re-opened again. A temporary dupe-hammer ban might be in order..

Comment: Those who voted to close the question or who think the question should be closed might like to know that John Conde, who answered the question, has self-servingly decided to unilaterally reopen it. If this is not abuse of the close/reopen hammer, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Louis Just got pointed in this direction. I went back to that question because I saw a lot of votes coming into my answer and thought it was odd (should have guessed meta effect). I saw the question was closed but didn't think it was a dupe of that question. If you and the community think I'm wrong that's ok. It can be still closed (and removed if so decided). I'm not married to the question or the answer. Life goes on.

Comment: I'm still curious.. why do you two think this isn't a duplicate? That's the root of the problem here, isn't it? It's been almost an hour and no one has given a reason for it to not be a dupe.

Comment: It seems that it was re-opened both times as a direct result of this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78119/room-for-jay-blanchard-fred-ii-and-john-conde

Comment: All I know is that posting this question has cost me a lot of reputation

Comment: @SmallLegend Question's now deleted, so any rep you lost will be refunded.

Comment: @bob I lost more reputation from you deleting it :O must have had a lot of upvotes as well as down haha, thanks anyway

Comment: @SmallLegend I didn't delete it, I don't have the rep.

Comment: @yourcommonsense Wow you managed to post a question here, that's actually upvoted. I even have to upvote (and vote to reopen) myself :-P Especially, when seeing that deleted answer below.

Comment: @SmallLegend It's sad that you got caught in a broader dispute not of your own making. This should have been handled better. Hopefully you still hang around. There's normally not this much drama over a duplicate question.

Comment: @Machavity _"There's normally not this much drama over a duplicate question."_ Unless you meet YCS :-P ...

Comment: There shouldn't be this much drama over a duplicate question no matter who is involved. Duplicate closure is a pretty straightforward thing, there was no reason for this much nonsense.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It appears that the question was reopened purely because a user with the Mjolnir saw that you had closed the question, and that user has a personal problem with you over unrelated incidents, rather than any meaningful disagreement over the close-state of that question.

The questions seem to be quite clearly duplicates, and nobody has provided any reasons for why they aren't duplicates, or for why the duplicate question doesn't solve the problem.  The question has been closed once again, so that should be that.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit (too much). For once, I agree with YCS, in that the question should remain closed, but the speculation in this answer was just poor taste.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I know, I cast one of the closure votes.

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought the way you had it you edited it to say it was reopened again, not about the original reopen.  please disregard the words that come out of my keyboard. ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not speculation.  The user has posted now-deleted comments personally insulting YCS, and stating that he had closed the question because of his past actions.  He has also refused to provide any reason for why the question isn't a duplicate.  It's also relevant to the question.  The question is "why was this reopened".  Saying, "a user reopened it" isn't answering that question; it's a *premise* of the question.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, the question in question has been deleted.

Comment: @Servy: Did the user re-opening the post ___Explicitly___ state he re-opened it because he disagrees with YCS? _Why_ a user does something  can _only_ be answered by _that user_.

Comment: Actually you missed the deleted comments @Cerbrus. The user in question basically did say that, yes.

Comment: @Cerbrus there's a link to a chatroom where user says "I'll reopen it, just to show him"... so.... yeah, it is pretty much explicit. I've NEVER been a fan of YCS and I do think everything he posts on meta is poisonous... but I believed higher reps would know not to just do stuff like that "because"

Comment: From what I read in Servy's reply, he only mentioned close-voting this post, or did he also explicitly say he re-opened that post because he disagrees with YCS?

Comment: I see, then my edit was out of place. I still think it's bad taste to defame a user in an answer, like this, but okay, it's based on actual events...

Comment: The user who reopened the question out of spite has ragequit SO... and good riddance, IMO.

Comment: @Patrice (and 14 upvoters), seriously? I do like YCS, as he often addresses issues that I also have with the site and its users. Granted, maybe it's not always phrased in the most constructive way possible, but I do agree with what he's saying in general. He seems to be concerned with maintaining quality on the site, and yeah, for that you need to have a controversial opinion sometimes. I don't like a "velvet glove" approach. The truth needs to be said.

Comment: @codecaster in an ideal world you'd be right and his approach would be justified.  Meta being what it is, stack being what it is, the way he brings these issues up, there's a better chance the community bucks up without reading it (as is happening now). Not a fan of the velvet glove either, but no more a fan of bashing my head changing a system the wrong way. The recent reaction to ANYTHING YCS does is negative.... just because. In the end he won't make any more progress than if he posts nothing, and he'll aggravate ppl along the way

Comment: @Patrice well there's a vast group of users that either only care about reputation or about helping the asker of any question, rather than caring about SO's original mission statement of becoming the greatest programming knowledge base. I encounter this on a daily basis when researching not-so-obvious things about the abysmally documented ASP.NET MVC framework, for example. There's a handful of users active in that tag that only copy code from blog posts without showing explanation, attribution or notices of version-specific pitfalls, and there's _thousands_ of such answers in that tag alone.

Comment: @CodeCaster I still believe there is a better way than simply posting the way he does and never answering anything. I'm with you a lot of the changes that should happen are pushed back "because" and that we need a cage rattler. But there's cage rattler and cage arsonist. A bit more diplomacy might go a long way here. I'm not saying it'll be easy, or quick. But the way YCS goes at it, it's just making things worse, as those people push back on him without even reading him anymore.

Comment: @Patrice I hardly think that how people have been automatically reacting to YCS can be blamed on YCS. He may or may not have said something that offended someone at some point and that should allow every other user to behave abhorrently? Every time he posts a question, whether legitimate and on-topic or not, the immediate response is for the normally somewhat well-behaved meta community at large to explode into a bunch of raving lunatics. That can in no way be blamed on YCS, that is each person's individual faults.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm not trying to impart blame here. I'm just saying it like it is. YES those users on a vendetta should read each post without looking at the OP. But things being the way they are.... he tries to change things. He's going at it the wrong way, considering how it's currently not working. I'm not attacking him or saying he's in the wrong. I'm saying the way he went and the reaction he's getting NOW shows that this kind of behavior won't bring any benefit to meta.

Comment: @Patrice: I can't accept that other users behaving badly can in anyway be blamed on him or anything that he has done in any way. If *he* behaves badly, yeah that's his fault and something should be done about that. But if him just being here causes other users to devolve into spiteful children, I fail to see how that can possibly be anyone's fault but their own. You can't say "He shouldn't do it that way" just because people respond badly. You should instead be saying "These people shouldn't be acting that way".

Comment: @TinyGiant AGAIN, I'm not trying to blame him. I'm just saying there's a point where one should realize the way he goes to try and change thing is tantamount to bashing his head to a wall. I'm just saying that if he wants things to change, he might want to try to change the way he brings things to meta. YES it's spiteful, childish and bad of users to react this way. What can WE do about it? not much. What can HE do about it? try to rub them a different way? Again, in an ideal world, we wouldn't need that. But this isn't an ideal world.

Comment: @TinyGiant I know that I personally find that a very large portion of YCS's meta posts are either off topic, not constructively worded, or both, despite the fact that he's attempting to discuss problems with the site that I very much believe he's correctly identified.  I would blame his poor presentation of his ideas as the reason that most people don't take him seriously and why he hasn't made progress at addressing the problem's he's bringing attention to.  I don't think *anyone* here is suggesting that he's to blame for people improperly voting on questions on the main site to spite him.

Comment: I feel like half the problem is simply a language problem. A lot of the points he makes are valid, and i agree with, but the presentation of it and grammar used are usually very blunt and direct, and people respond negatively to it. A developer i work with in europe comes across very blunt and direct too, and english also isn't his native language, so i wouldn't be surprised if that's what is happening here.

Comment: @KevinB might be a possibility. I've certainly observed myself, as well, that some non-native English speakers have difficulty expressing themselves in more subtle, nuanced, and diplomatic ways, in order to avoid offending and stuff like that. Plus, there could be cultural factors at play, such as cultures where a thicker skin to blunt manners of speaking are more of a norm.

Comment: @JayBlanchard And yet, even that, doesn't excuse reopening questions that he's closed, that merit closure, just to spite him.  There's no real point in trying to create a list of things that YCS has done that you don't like, or that you think are wrong.  None of them will ever justify such an action.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Then that's just off topic.  This isn't a "list everything you don't like about YCS, or that he's done wrong" thread.

Answer (score -12):

To set the record straight and for those who can't see the question because of low rep, here's the original question:

> Trying to create an is_member function, to check whether the user is or is not a member.
>
> Continually getting the same error despite doing as it says
>
> ```
>   $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname); //used to connect to the database
>
>   if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
>        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
>   }
>
>   // premium check function
>
>   function is_premium(){
>       $premium_query = mysqli_query($mysqli ,"SELECT 'is_member' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
>       $premium = mysqli_result($premium_query, 0, 'is_member');
>       if($premium =='1'){
>           return true;
>       }else{
>           return false;
>       }
>   } 
>   ?>
> ```

Pay particular attention to this bit:

```
SELECT 'is_member' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'
```

Notice the quotes instead of ticks? I can't see why the question was closed with [Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

It had nothing to do with the problem. What he should have chosen as a duplicate question was [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

**Prove me wrong.**

My comment under the question stating that he chose the wrong question was removed and I have no idea why, which went along the lines of my telling him that he chose the wrong question to close it with.

It's pretty obvious that he downvoted perfectly good answers and closed some that I've answered to; I'm not the only one who has a problem with him, others do.

This is the classic *the pot calling the kettle black*.

There, I've said my piece and have "set the record straight". Now you know the "real" truth.

Comment: Hmya, you have to know by now that he will keep torturing and annoying you until you blow up and do something stoopid.  And everybody will go "ohmigod, look at what Fred did!"  And he'll go "hehehe".  You'll have to out-smart him.  Only way that works is by biting your tongue and wait until the moderators have had enough of him again.  You can do it, hang in there.

Comment: Are you just trolling now?  Because that's not what your buddy's answer says.  Also, the error being raised is a PHP error, not a MySQL error.  The first parameter to mysqli_query isn't even that string.

Comment: I mean, that's certainly one problem in the question, but it's not the main problem, it's something that will come up after the first problem is solved. I'd consider that to be a separate issue in need of a new question.

Comment: So all your post is saying is *"Let's blame this guy, not me.*". Hmm..

Comment: I think that really this is indicative of "your" truth, not necessarily the "real" truth. Whether YCS was wrong or not, you were well out of line with your responses. Saying someone else is behaving badly while behaving badly yourself is most definitely a case of "*the pot calling the kettle black*", but on your part rather than anyone else's.

Comment: Let it go already, you'll feel a lot better about it too ;-)